# How to display non-common rows in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008. I have three table tableA,tableB and table C.In table A, i have two columns one is Employeeid and another one is Projectid.In table B, i have two columns one is employeeid and another one is Employeename.In table C, i have two columns one is projectid and next one is project name.

i used following query to display non-common rows from tableA and table B(Unmatched Employeeid)

```
   SELECT A.EmployeeID FROM A 
   EXCEPT
   SELECT B.EmployeeID FROM B
```

i want to display projectname also in addition to Employeeid.
i.e) i need like this:

```
    Employeeid|projectname
    1         |ABC
    2         |XYZ
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this using sql server 2008?

Comment: Conventionally "non-common" (meaning "not *in* common") is the term used here, rather than "uncommon" (which usually means "not common").

Answer (score 5):

I would just use a `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID, C.ProjectName
FROM A
INNER JOIN C
    ON A.ProjectID = C.ProjectID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID)
```

Comment: :i want project name which is in table c.